# jquery google map does not reload after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I downloaded the jquery map from the following link:
[enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/source/browse/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-data-attribute.html?r=300)

and it works properly but as soon as I add for example a clickable div named test1 and put the code related to the loading the map in that and click on it nothing happen this is the code :

```
$(".test1").click(function() {
            $("#test1").append("<li data-gmapping=" +
                "'{\"id\":\"m_1\",\"latlng\":   {\"lat\":27.6648274,\"lng\":-81.51575350000002},\"tags\":\"drupal\"}'>" +
                "<p class=\"info-box\">Florida DrupalCamp - Feb 11 2012</p></li>");
        demo.add(function() {

            alert("ddddd");
            $('#map_canvas').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                var self = this;

                $("[data-gmapping]").each(function(i,el) {

                    var data = $(el).data('gmapping');
                    alert($(el).find('.info-box').text());
                    self.addMarker({'id': data.id, 'tags':data.tags, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(data.latlng.lat, data.latlng.lng), 'bounds':true }, function(map,marker) {

                        $(el).click(function() {
                            $(marker).triggerEvent('click');

                        });
                    }).click(function() {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': $(el).find('.info-box').text() }, this);
                    });
                });                     
            }});
        }).load();


    });
```

It is noteworthy that alert("ddddd");  works now but as soon as I put it in

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
```

it does not work it seems that $('#map_canvas').gmap is assigned just once and never get assigned anymore

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first remove(destroy) the map-functionality:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy').gmap({/*options for initialization*/});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but when I do what you suggested I get the following alarm box message: Unable to load due ...some CDNs are not responsive as we would like to be

Comment: I instead use $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy') first then add the normal code for binding gmap now it works :) Thanks a lot for your smart answer

Comment: Just a quick question: for the map that I am using how can I add marker to the map without rebinding gmap again . Now when I use this method I get a little refresh like till the new marker adds which is not gallant

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? When you add another marker on each click this would make no sense, because the data for this marker are the same, it would be exact copy of the marker at the same location(the latest added marker would cover the previous markers)

Comment: No I mean in the future scenario that I am going to implement I will read lat and lng from database

Comment: call addMarker: `$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {/*marker-options*/});` . The callback will only be executed when the map has been initialized, on later calls it will be ignored. You may call addMarker without initializing the map, it will be initialized automatically.